# How do I get metrics value in my code in .net 7 app?

Tags: c#, metrics, .net-7.0

I create a counter like this:

```
meter = new Meter("MyApp");
subsCounter = meter.CreateUpDownCounter<int>("ObjectsSubscriptions");
```

I want to print `subsCounter` during debug. How can i get current value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/metrics-instrumentation

you should use `MetricCollector` with `var measurements = collector.GetMeasurementSnapshot()`

```cs
class HatCoMetricsWithGlobalMeter
{
    static Meter s_meter = new Meter("HatCo.Store");
    static Counter<int> s_hatsSold = s_meter.CreateCounter<int>("hatco.store.hats_sold");

    public void HatsSold(int quantity)
    {
        s_hatsSold.Add(quantity);
    }
}

public class MetricTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void SaleIncrementsHatsSoldCounter()
    {
        // Arrange
        var metrics = new HatCoMetricsWithGlobalMeter();
        // Be careful specifying scope=null. This binds the collector to a global Meter and tests
        // that use global state should not be configured to run in parallel.
        var collector = new MetricCollector<int>(null, "HatCo.Store", "hatco.store.hats_sold");

        // Act
        metrics.HatsSold(15);

        // Assert
        var measurements = collector.GetMeasurementSnapshot();
        Assert.Equal(1, measurements.Count);
        Assert.Equal(15, measurements[0].Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this _answer_ doing this "I want to print subsCounter during debug. How can i get current value?" ?

Comment: In the `SaleIncrementsHatsSoldCounter` is your answer. Get collector. Get snapshot. Get values from it

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [`MeterListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.metrics.meterlistener?view=net-7.0) to receive recording notifications, here's an example.

```
var listener = new MeterListener();
var v = 0;
listener.EnableMeasurementEvents(subsCounter);
listener.SetMeasurementEventCallback<int>((i, m, t, s) =>
{
    Interlocked.Add(ref v, m);
    Console.WriteLine(v);
});
```

You may also use tools like [`dotnet-counters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-counters) to collect the value. (It doesn't support `UpDownCounter` yet, but the new version to be released this month should include this feature.)

Comment: just to explain - dotnet-counters is not acceptable in this use case as i need it in debug time - i cant find the way to connect it to VS when is debugging. Also I couldnt find way to run VS perf tools and display custom counters. so i am trying now to print them manually during debug